# cgi-node.js complains of missing file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm setting up cgi-node on a dedicated server using the guidance provided at www.cgi-node.org.  I've modified the first line of cgi-node.js to point to my node executable as instructed.  I am getting the following complaint:

```
EXCEPTION: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'D:/Programs/nodejs/sessions/2bbaca3254cea595a0f2b24f204f0a87'
```

I was a bit surprised by the reference to a Windows-style path since I'm running Linux.  However, examination of the source code for cgi-node.js reveals that that path is hard-coded into the configuration.  Is this another modification that I should be making or what?  Thanks for any input.

```
  ... doug
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm looks like there's a session path variable that needs to be modified too (approx line 47 in the non-optimized download, version 0.2):

```
var CgiNodeConfig = 
{ 
   //
   // .... blah blah other stuff
   // 

   SessionPath: '/var/foo/sessions'  // <-- change this
};
```

Comment: Yes, that's the exact line that I'm talking about.  :-)  I'm assuming that when you say, "modified too" you mean in addition to the modification made in the first line.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: haha my reading comprehension is not so great today...  ok so i see what you're saying. i dug into the github repo just now ... the author does mention something about needing to change this variable in a (sort of) recent comment (https://github.com/UeiRicho/cgi-node/issues/13#issuecomment-82035427). seems the online docs are stale and this is a legit change that does in fact need to be done at initial setup

Comment: Thanks for that input.  The github info seems to be pretty clear that that line needs to be modified.  I think that I'm over that hurdle; but, now I'm getting a Cannot-read-property-'session'-of-null error.  I'm getting the feeling that this session thing was added recently and thre may still be a few kinks and/or the documentation hasn't caught up.  Thanks again for the input.